# How to track location by ip address in python

Tags: python

As you see this code I am trying to locate the user location using IP but it not working.

```
import pygeoip
gip = pygeoip.GeoIP("GeoLiteCity.dat")
res=gip.record_by_addr('Enter the ip')
for key,val in res.items():
   print('%s : %s' % (key,val))
```

Comment: Use an external Geolocation API service like `http://ip-api.com/json/24.48.0.1`. Send a GET request to the link.

Comment: Please make sure path of the GeoLiteCity.dat is correct.

Comment: @Vishnudev You might hit the usuage limit using such external services

Comment: Many have high limits and all of them are listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/5120049

Comment: Number of limits is subjective based on your scale of the project. You might end up paying huge if you are serving millions of users.

Comment: I think we should stick to solve the question using the local database.